# Android debug not working saying waiting for debugger

Tags: android, eclipse

Before you downvote it please read my problem first. I know this has been in stackoverflow topic but i cant seem to figure out why its not working to me.
I tried to put  `android:debuggable="true"` and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"></uses-permission>
```

in the manifest. Even in the emulator it doesnt work. I use eclipse juno. Anyone has an idea how to fix this?

I even restart my phone but no luck. Thanks

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.breakpoint"
    android:versionCode="1"

    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:debuggable="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you found the solution to this? I'm stuck at the same problem too :\